# Is it possible to create custom GraphServiceClient in UiPath? (and how)

Tags: vb.net, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, uipath

We are needing additional Office 365 functionality that is not provided by the standard Office 365 package by UiPath (such as marking emails as read/not read, changing the subject lines of emails already in a shared mailbox, etc).

Having looked through Microsoft documentation, it should be possible via code - but this doesn't seem to work in UiPath.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS

UiPath moans that it needs netstandard version 2.0.0.0 to create a new GraphServiceClient - however, I don't think that I'm able to add that assembly to the project.

Does anyone know how we can create the custom graph connection in UiPath?

Answer (score 1):

As I don't want to copy the doc page, all you need is written on [**Github (Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library)**](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

> The Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library targets .NetStandard 2.0 and
> .Net Framework 4.6.2.

To install the client library via NuGet:

- Search for `Microsoft.Graph` in the NuGet Library, or
- Type `Install-Package Microsoft.Graph` into the Package Manager Console.

For UiPath setup, use your link. Should work in the `Invoke code` block.